# Laravel installer not installing latest version

Tags: laravel

I have attempted installing Laravel 5.7 with the Laravel installed and composer create-project but both install 5.6.34

I have specified the 5.7.0 and dev-develop branch in my composer command. When I specify 5.7.0 I get the following exception:

> Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.7.*

When I specify dev-develop it installs 5.6.34 - I assume 5.7 has been released as it is available on the Laravel website with upgrade instructions.

Anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.7 is not officially released yet, but you can get the latest commit from github master branch like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:dev-master myproject --dev
```

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it had been released with it having release notes etc on the website. Anyhow, I have just tried your command but get the same result - 5.6.34 installed

Comment: @showFocus, yes in composer it says 5.6.34, but when I compared with latest commit from git its the same.